# How to style autocomplete multiple selected values?

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I want to create an autocomplete multiple but with a comma in selected values. When I choose multiple values, it makes bigger the component.

[AutoComplete codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zm929?file=/demo.js)

But I want to make autocomplete just like select with multiple option.

[Select CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/g17t2?file=/demo.js)

First image shows how autocomplete behaves in multiple selection. Second image, what I want when multiple selection occurs.

[image: Here is how autocomplete behave in multiple selected]

[image: Here is what I want]